# Steps Of Implementation of A Single-Round Encryption Scheme

Tags: encryption

**Hi,I am new to cryptography.
I do not understand 5th step could anyone explain me please.**

1) Read a plaintext from a file block-by-block with block size of 10 characters. Please note that plaintext file must contain more than 10 lines of text.

2) A permutation of length 10 is chosen to be IP = 10 8 6 4 2 9 7 5 3 1. The 10-character text blocks are passed through the initial permutation (IP).

3) Use Table 1 to encode characters so that each character will be 8 bits of length.

Table 1: Character encoding

A-00000001 B-00000010 C-00000011 Ç-00000100 D-00000101 E-00000110
F-00000111 G-00001000 Ğ-00001001 H-00001010 I-00001011 İ-00001100
J-00001101 K-00001110 L-00001111 M-00010000 N-00010001 O-00010010
Ö-00010011 P-00010100 R-00010101 S-00010110 Ş-00010111 T-00011000
U-00011001 Ü-00011010 V-00011011 Y-00011100 Z-00011101

4) Preform a Shift-right-rotate operation with 4 positions on the encoded characters.

5) Get 2 characters at a time from the encoded block: Characters at odd positions are placed into the left nibble and characters with even 
positions are placed into the right nibble.

6) Choose a 16-bit (2 characters) key (K) and pass it through the one’s complement operation before generating two 8-bit keys called K2 and K3. Note that these sub-keys are derived by splitting key K1 into 2 equal parts, see Fig.1.

7) Each 8-bit character from the partitions is XOR’d with the corresponding key.

8) XOR’d partitions are now swapped; left became right, and vice versa.

9) Now, two new sub-keys (K4 and K5) are generated by permuting key K2 and K3 and rotating the new keys separately, see Fig.1.

10) The swapped partitions are XOR’d with the new sub-keys.

11) Partitions are swapped again and merged.

12) Finally a cipher block is obtained by passing the resulting 10-character block through the reverse permutation.

13) Encrypted blocks will be saved in a ciphertext file.

14) Finally, verify your encryption by decrypting the ciphertext file.

[image]

Comment: That algorithm looks like it was designed by a drunken monkey.

Comment: My guess is that they start with 2 bytes, divide it into four 4-bit nibbles, and then interleave them, so that one of the output bytes consists of the two high nibbles, the other byte of the two low nibbles. i.e it turns `aaaabbbb ccccdddd` into `aaaacccc bbbbdddd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to crypto-SE. However, it seems the algorithm you pasted is not actual cryptography.

## This algorithm is what we call [Snake Oil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_oil_(cryptography)).

The first sign of why this is bogus: The key is just $16$ bit long (step 6 and in the graph). That is just silly.

The second sign is what is actually missing: There is no argument why this is secure. No explanation, no formal proof, nothing.

The third sign would be: After a first glance at the algorithm, there is no indication of any non-linear function, any hard-to-invert function, etc. Also, there are no multiple rounds, which should raise some suspicion.

If you're serious about learning cryptography, I suggest choosing your sources more carefully, e.g. articles and books by well-known authors, material of university courses, etc. The articles on Wikipedia about cryptography are also quite good and always provide good references at the bottom of the page.